# How to read SSAS Extended Event session data from Ring Buffer

Tags: sql-server, logging, ssas

I am running an Extended Events session on my SSAS instance, which logs events to a Ring Buffer.

I would like to read these events from the ring buffer, but I cannot find the place where they are stored.

So far I am unable to see the events in sys.dm_os_ring_buffers, which I understand should be the place they appear. Only SQL Server (Database Engine) related events seem to be logged here.

Is there are separate area in which SSAS saves events logged to a ring buffer?

Comment: After doing some more research, it appears that it won't matter much if I read the XML data created by the XEvent sesstion from either data source. So making sure it's actually read from a ring buffer than from the file system seems not to make an impact big enough warranting looking further into this solution. The bottleneck rather seems to be transforming the data from XML into SELECTable format on a column basis.

Answer (score 1):

The results are stored in the `TARGET_DATA` column of the SSAS (**not** SQL Server) `$SYSTEM.DISCOVER_XEVENT_SESSION_TARGETS` DMV.  The data is stored in XML Format.  To query this DMV, connect to SSAS through SSMS and open a new query editor window (`CTRL + N`) such as you would for an MDX or DAX query.  Then you can query the DMV as follows.

```
SELECT 
    TARGET_DATA 
FROM $SYSTEM.DISCOVER_XEVENT_SESSION_TARGETS 
WHERE SESSION_NAME = 'YourExtendedEventSession'
```

Comment: This returns an empty column for the XEvents Session I started with Ring Buffer as data target and it returns an XML specifying the path of the file for another session I created with File as data target.

I am looking for the actual events however, just as they are written to the file destination.

Comment: What type of cube (tabular/multidimensional) are you using?  Using a tabular model at the 1100 compatibility level that column is populated for me.  And the same events you're monitoring are written to a file when this is used as a destination, correct?

Comment: It's a MD cube. I have set up two sessions, one writes to file system one writes to a ring buffer. I am on SQL Server 2016 which is version 130 I believe?

Comment: I'm not sure about multidimensional, but for SSAS 2016 tabular models the compatibility level can vary.  Both sessions have the same events, and the events are written to the session using a file target, right?